# Perl Mojolicious Rename App Script

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Is it possible to rename a mojolicious app? I am generating an app with
    **mojo generate app MyWebApp**
and after I while I would like to rename the app and all the files that contains my MyWebApp(including the use MyWebApp::Controller::Name etc.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# change file contents
grep -l -r MyWebApp | xargs perl -i -lpe's/MyWebApp/CoolNewWebApp/'

# change file names
find | xargs rename 's/MyWebApp/CoolNewWebApp/'
find | xargs rename 's/my_web_app/cool_new_web_app/'
```

You get the rename command with `cpanm File::Rename`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast reply, but will this work with mojolicious? I am asking because when you create a mojolicious app with mojo generate app MyWebApp will create the next files https://pastebin.com/gW9REeQj
  As you can see even if the app name is MyWebApp, mojolicious creates some files with My_Web_App and some with MyWebApp . Sorry if my explanation is not very well.

Comment: Yes, I tested it.

Comment: hmm, for some reason i tried and the old app name still remains.  first app: https://pastebin.com/48Y34Cxc after executing the comands I get this https://pastebin.com/9L0GfH7b . Steps I've made: 1) cd into app folder, execute grep -l -r MyWebApp | xargs perl -i -lpe's/MyWebApp/CoolNewWebApp/' 2) find | xargs rename 's/MyWebApp/CoolNewWebApp/' 3) cd out of app folder and execute mv my_web_app cool_new_web_app

Comment: I'm very sorry, you are right; I overlooked these two files, that's totally my mistake. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Cool! Thank you!